# How to use Exposé independently on multiple monitors? (Mac)

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

I've got 2 monitors, and in order to activate an Exposé "hot corner", I'd like to simply be able to move my cursor to the corner of my current screen. Is this possible?

At present, to use the top left corner I have to go to the top left of the left-hand monitor, while the top right corner only works on the right-hand monitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a kludge at best but in the Displays Preference Pane if you choose the Arrangement tab - set have it so the monitors are not 100% lined up - that is the right monitor's left corner is above the right corner of the left monitor so that the left corner is an actual corner instead of simply a place to cross over from one monitor to the next.

It doesn't work for all 4 corners at the same time but if you only use one to two corners it gets the job done even if it's exceptionally non-intuitive and a rather annoying bug.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Not a kludge at all, does the job exactly as I wanted! Thanks.